# Comparing the length of 2 lists in Haskell

Tags: haskell, compare

im new to Haskell and currently making a few activities to test myself. The main reason i created this post is because im stuck in a situation that im not so sure its possible to solve the way im doing.
The exercise that i've been trying to do asks to count how many repeated integers are in a list. Well, i tried to do it by recursion but i was not able to solve it like that (mainly because I'm inexperienced in the language and I couldn't follow the tutorials already present in the stackoverflow).

So I tried to copy my list using `Set.fromList` and having a copy generated without the duplicated elements in a way that I would only have to compare the size of the two lists and I would have my quantity.

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

list :: [a] -> Int  
list xs = length xs
 
copyList = [1,2,2,4,4]

y =  Set.fromList copyLista




main::IO()

main = do

  print (list[1,2,3,3])
```

I implemented the code above but I don't know if there is any way for `y` to receive the values ​​that were passed to list . It was only possible to put it manually, again as in the code above `[1,2,2,4,4]`

Could someone give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you mean by the ‘values that were passed to list’ — could you elaborate? As for your problem, you shouldn’t need sets for this: `Data.List` includes a function `nub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]` which deduplicates a list, so you should be able to do this by comparing `length xs` and `length (nub xs)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot bradrn, I meant the values ​​passed to the "list" function in the last list line [1,2,3,3].
I was trying to store those values ​​in copylist.

Anyway, I tested using the "nub" and I was successful, I appreciate the tip.

Comment: @bradrn I'd hesitate to recommend `nub` ever, because it's crazy inefficient. Unless you know the lists will always be very short, you definitely _should_ use sets.

Comment: Thanks for the info @leftaroundabout! I’d heard that `nub` is inefficient, but I had no idea it was _that_ inefficient; I thought it was fine as long as your lists aren’t overly long. (Though doesn’t `containers` contain an [efficient `nub`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Containers-ListUtils.html#v:nubOrd)? Though hmm, looks like that one uses `Set` internally…)

Answer (score 0):

First off, defining `list = length` like you did doesn't make any sense. Just use `length` right away.

But if what you actually want this to do is determining *how many elements are in a set* then there's a different function for that. Ask Hoogle what it's called: [`https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Set a -> Int`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Set+a+-%3E+Int)

Aha, it is [`Set.size`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.4.1/docs/Data-Set.html#v:size). So what you probably want is

```
main = do
  print $ Set.size y
```